# How to color the cell that contains the maximum value in a line with kableExtra?

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I would like to color only the cell that contains the highest value in the first row of my table (kableExtra).

For example, if the highest value is `98.32` the background color should be red.

My data:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "kable")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

body <- dashboardBody(htmlOutput(outputId = "simul"))

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$simul <- renderText({
    
    df_1 <- data.frame(x = replicate(n = 5, expr = runif(n = 10, min = 20, max = 100)))
    
    df_1 %>%
      kableExtra::kable(x = .,row.names = F, format = "html",
                        col.names = lapply(X = 1:length(.), FUN = function(x) {
                          names <- paste("Var", x, sep = " ")
                          })) %>%
      kableExtra::kable_styling(font_size = 16, bootstrap_options = "striped") %>%
      kableExtra::kable_styling() %>%
      kableExtra::row_spec(kable_input = ., row = 0, background = "#008cba", color = "#f2f2f2") %>% 
      kableExtra::row_spec(kable_input = ., row = 1, 
                           background = ifelse(test = (max(as.numeric(.)) == which.max(as.numeric(.))), 
                                               yes = "red", no = "white"), 
                           color = "#020202")
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The problem is in this part of the code.

```
  kableExtra::row_spec(kable_input = ., row = 1, 
                       background = ifelse(test = (max(as.numeric(.)) == which.max(as.numeric(.))), 
                                           yes = "red", no = "white"), 
                       color = "#020202")
```

So again, if the highest value is `98.32` in line 1 the background color should be `red` (and just this cell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `cell_spec`.
`escape` parameter from `kable` **must be set to** `FALSE` in order to interpret correctly the associated `html`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
set.seed(123)
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "kable")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

body <- dashboardBody(htmlOutput(outputId = "simul"))

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$simul <- renderText({
    
    df_1 <- data.frame(x = replicate(n = 5, expr = runif(n = 10, min = 20, max = 100)))
    
    cmax <- which.max(df_1[1,])
    
    df_1[1, cmax] <- kableExtra::cell_spec(df_1[1, cmax],format =  "html", background = "red",color = "#020202")
    
    # Needed : escape = FALSE
    df_1 %>% kable( row.names = F,format = "html", escape = FALSE,
                    col.names = lapply(X = 1:length(.), FUN = function(x) {
                      names <- paste("Var", x, sep = " ")})) %>%
      kableExtra::kable_styling(font_size = 16, bootstrap_options = "striped")  %>%
      kableExtra::row_spec(kable_input = ., row = 0, background = "#008cba", color = "#f2f2f2")
      
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]